# how to define a groovy class with a main function that creates a new object that is an instance of another class

Tags: groovy

Sorry, I'm a groovy newbie and obviously just not getting it, but 
please could anyone explain why I get these errors when compiling
the following code:

tc.groovy:

```
 class t
 {
   int v;
   t() { v = 1; }
 }
 class tt
 {
   static void main(String[] args)
   {
     t v = new t();
   }
 }
```

$ groovyc tc.groovy

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

tc.groovy: 11: Apparent variable 'v' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:

You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.

You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.

You attempted to use a method 'v' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.

```
 @ line 11, column 12.
        t v = new t();
          ^
```

1 error

All I'm trying to do is compile a groovy program that declares 2 classes, one with a main() method, which needs to instantiate an instance of the other class.  Is there any way to do this in groovy?

Comment: If I split the above file into 2 files, 't.groovy' declaring class t,
and tt.groovy declaring class tt, the 't.groovy' file compiles OK with
groovyc, but the tt.groovy file gets the same error.

I thought groovy had the same variable initialization syntax as Java ?

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize your class name to T, change the constructor to match, and it will work. Groovy requires that the type name begin with a capital letter.

This is a difference from Java. In Java there is no hard requirement that class names must be capitalized, it is only a convention. In Groovy it is not just a convention, the grammar of the language assumes all classes will start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was it. Doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere in the groovy documention I have.

Comment: @JVD, Groovy is supposed to interoperate with Java. The reason this is not part of the Groovy documentation is probably because capitalizing class names is already a part of the Java documentation itself. By the way, you may want to accept Nathan's answer by clicking on the little check mark next to his answer. Accepting his answer will ensure that search engines know that the question was answered. Also, you should delete your other answers and your other comment, and fold everything back into your original question by clicking on its edit link and updating the question there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Aha ! If I change:

```
t v = new t();
```

to

```
def v = new t();
```

it compiles.

But I know which class I want to create an instance of : 't' .

Isn't it possible to create an instance of a specified class in groovy ?

Comment: it would be better to post these kinds of things as edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ONLY occurs for ANY user-defined class - ie:

```
class c {}
...
c v = new c();
```

would produce the error, while :

```
String v = new String();
```

would not .

I'm guessing this is a groovy bug - I'm going to report it as one.