# Is there any java code which cannot be compiled by Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm working on a class for a group of Java dev colleagues that want to learn more about Groovy, which I know well enough to do work in it, but not at an academic level.

I want to start with "All java is Groovy" to assuage the inevitable "change of language" anxiety, but these being developers, will go out of their way to find an edge case where this is not true.  I was hoping to head them off at the pass and point these out ahead of time, but I couldn't think of any.

Comment: which java language version are we talking about?

Comment: Thanks.  Any, really, but let's go with java 7 to avoid the lambda stuff.

Comment: just remembered, groovy classes have stricter naming requirements than java ones, see [how to define a groovy class with a main function that creates a new object that is an instance of another class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28905499/217324).  The [question i closed this as a duplicate of](http://stackoverflow.com/q/687601/217324) is probably still not complete (though still worth reading, i think), so reopening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all Java is Groovy (sorry to burst your bubble) ;-)

Apart from the differences [described in the documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html), there are a few others:

- Array initialisation `{}` vs `[]`
- `do..while` blocks don't exist in Groovy
- Lambdas aren't part of the Groovy parser

Plus there's probably a few others

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Will "check" this when I'm able (timeout requirement of SO.)

Comment: Your point 1 and 3 appear in the documentation as "3. Array initializers" and "7. Lambdas"

Comment: Haha, whoops...  Still worth repeating ;-)